# How to specify soft constraints using prolog? (puzzle with soft constraints)

Tags: prolog

I've been given as an assignment to solve a puzzle using prolog.

Being a beginner in prolog, who just read a couple of online tutorials on prolog the last few hours, I have no idea how to even start this..

The puzzle is much larger scale and has more constraints, but I will simplify it here because I just want to get the idea so I can scale it later.

The puzzle goes like this:
You need to schedule shifts for 2 employees, A and B, for the week.(including weekends)
Rules:

1. In a single day, either A or B (but not both) must be working
2. A must work on Tuesday
3. no one can work continuously for more than 2 days

Soft constraints:

1. A prefers to work on Thursday (add 2 points if A works on Thursday )
2. B dislike to work on Wednesday (add 5 points if B doesn't work on Wednesday)

The chart:

```
|--------|--------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|----------| 
|        | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
|--------|--------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|----------| 
|    A   |        |        |         |           |          |        |          |
|--------|--------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|----------|
|    B   |        |        |         |           |          |        |          |
|--------|--------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|----------|
```

How to schedule this so that can achieve the highest points possible?

One possible solution (there are several) will be:

```
|--------|--------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|----------| 
|        | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
|--------|--------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|----------| 
|    A   |        |        |    X    |     X     |          |        |     X    |
|--------|--------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|----------|
|    B   |    X   |    X   |         |           |     X    |    X   |          |
|--------|--------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|----------|
```

The maximum we can get is 5 points. Since there's no solution that can get full marks of 7 points while satisfying all rules.

Question that I have:

1. How do we set rules with soft constraints? Since it is impossible to respect all the rules under soft constraints above, have to decide which one to take base on highest points.
2. How to represent a 2d array such as above in prolog? I have read about List, but not sure how to represent a 2d List.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need a 2D list, a single list of 7 items (a or b) is possible (according to rule 1).

Comment: If you want a list like an array, you have a list of lists [[a,b],...] or a list of tuples [(a,b), ...

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the real puzzle there are like ABCDEFGH and one day needs to have 3 people working at the same time, so I think a single list won't work in that case. Is there a tutorial where I can learn about list of lists? For example how to add a rule that says any row cannot have three continuous shifts?

Comment: You can play with nth0/3 for example nth0(1, [a,b,c], b) succeeds but nth0(1, [a,b,c], a) fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prolog, for simple problems, we can try to apply a simple 'pattern', plain old [generate and test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_and_error), interesting for its simplicity. We 'just' provide appropriate domain generator and test.

```
generate(D0, D) :-
    length(D0, DL),
    length(D, DL),
    maplist(dom_element, D).
dom_element(a).
dom_element(b).

test(D, Score, D) :-
    D = [_Sunday, _Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, _Friday, _Saturday],

    % 1. In a single day, either A or B (but not both) must be working
    %    Here True by construction

    % 2. A must work on Tuesday
    Tuesday = a,

    % 3. no one can work continuously for more than 2 days
    no_more_than_2(D),

    % soft 1. A prefers to work on Thursday (add 2 points if A works on Thursday )
    ( Thursday = a -> S1 is 2 ; S1 is 0 ),

    % soft 2. B dislike to work on Wednesday (add 5 points if B doesn't work on Wednesday)
    ( Wednesday \= b -> S2 is 5 ; S2 is 0 ),

    Score is S1 + S2.

% edit: jshimpfs suggestion, beside being much better, highlights a bug
no_more_than_2(D) :-
    nth0(I, D, E),
    length(D, L),
    J is (I+1) mod L,
    nth0(J, D, E),
    K is (J+1) mod L,
    nth0(K, D, E),
    !, fail.
no_more_than_2(_).

solve(D0, Best) :-
    D0 = [sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat],
    setof(Score/Sol, D^(generate(D0, D), test(D, Score, Sol)), All),
    last(All, Best).
```

test:

```
?- solve(_,L).
L = 5/[b, b, a, a, b, b, a].
```

Comment: I find using nth/3 almost always a bad idea. What about `no_more_than_2(Xs) :- append(_, [Xm,Xn], Xs), \+ append(_, [X,X,X|_], [Xm,Xn|Xs]).`

Comment: @jschimpf: much better and highlights a bug in mine !

Answer (score 2):

Plain Prolog is probably not the best choice here.  Such problems are most easily modelled using 0/1 Integer Programming, and solved with an IP or Finite-Domain solver, which several enhanced Prologs provide.  Here is a solution in [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org) (disclaimer: I'm a co-developer).  The soft constraints are handled via an objective function.

```
:- lib(ic).
:- lib(ic_global_gac).
:- lib(branch_and_bound).

schedule(Points, As, Bs) :-
    As = [_ASu,_AMo, ATu,_AWe, ATh,_AFr,_ASa],      
    Bs = [_BSu,_BMo,_BTu, BWe,_BTh,_BFr,_BSa],      

    As :: 0..1,
    Bs :: 0..1,
    ( foreach(A,As), foreach(B,Bs) do A+B #= 1 ),    % Rule 1
    ATu = 1,                                         % Rule 2
    sequence(0, 2, 3, As),            % 0..2 out of 3, Rule 3
    sequence(0, 2, 3, Bs),

    Points #= 2*ATh + 5*(1-BWe),                     % Soft

    Cost #= -Points,
    append(As, Bs, ABs),
    minimize(labeling(ABs), Cost).


?- schedule(P, As, Bs).
P = 5
As = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
Bs = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
Yes (0.03s cpu)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Actually the puzzle didn't specifically mentioned prolog but my friend highly suggested it. Perhaps I am in the wrong direction all these while. I will have a look into ECLiPSe. Thanks again!